# Is there a way to make targeted banner ads on moodle 2.8?

Tags: ads, moodle, sidebar

I have just upgraded to Moodle 2.8 and I want to include some advertising within the site.  The ads could appear on the side bar as a square or as a banner above the main content.  I am using the Theme called BCU.

I only want the ads to show on certain courses and not on others.

Is there a way to do it without having to manually include in on each course?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Create a simple block - https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Blocks

Use the applicable formats so it only displays on course and module pages and check if the current course is in the target.

Something like this for the class in `/blocks/course_advert/block_course_advert.php`

```
class block_course_advert extends block_base {
    function init() {
        $this->title = get_string('pluginname', 'block_course_advert');
    }

    function applicable_formats() {
        // Only appear on course pages and course module pages.
        return array('all' => false, 'course' => true, 'mod' => true, );
    }

    function get_content() {
        global $DB;

        if($this->content !== NULL) {
            return $this->content;
        }

        if (empty($this->instance)) {
            return '';
        }

        // Check if this course matches your target audience.
        // This is just an example, you will probably have a more complex query.
        $sql = "SELECT id
                FROM {course}
                WHERE " .$DB->sql_like('summary', ':summary') . "
                AND id = :id";
        $params = array('id' => $this->page->course->id, 'summary' => 'some target text');
        if (!$DB->record_exists_sql($sql, $params)) {
            // Doesn't match so hide the block.
            return '';
        }

        $this->content = new stdClass();
        $advert = 'some text';
        $this->content->text = format_text($advert);
        $this->content->footer = '';

        return $this->content;
    }

    function hide_header() {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Russell, that is exactly what I was after.